# Optaplanner : Problem while working with custom shadow variable

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to test out custom shadow variables to use them on a project I am working on, and I tried to do a simple example to test it out.
In my PlanningEntity I have a genuine planning variable (I named it x) of type Integer and the custom shadow variable (I named it y) of same type Integer.
The variable listener I used is as such :

```
public class yVariableListener implements VariableListener<Planningsolution, variable> {

@Override
public void beforeEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, variable variable) {
    // Do nothing

}

@Override
public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, variable variable) {
    // Do nothing
}

@Override
public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, variable variable) {
    // Do nothing
    
}

@Override
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, variable variable) {
    
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(sourcevariable, "x");
    sourcevariable.setY(sourcevariable.getX()*10);
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(sourcevariable, "x");

}

@Override
public void beforeEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, variable variable) {
    // Do nothing
}

@Override
public void afterEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, variable variable) {
    // Do nothing
}
}
```

In the constraint provider, I am trying to maximize the value of the shadow variable (soft score), and I am having a hard score that the genuine variable is less than a certain amount.
When I run the solver, I get the following error :

> 2022-09-29 12:56:21,613 [main] INFO  Solving started: time spent
> (156), best score (-1init/0hard/0soft), environment mode
> (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
> variableListener (class solver.yVariableListener) has been notified
> with notifiedCount (1) but after being triggered, its
> notificationCount (2) is different. Maybe that variableListener (class
> solver.yVariableListener) changed an upstream shadow variable (which
> is illegal).  at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.listener.support.AbstractNotifiable.triggerAllNotifications(AbstractNotifiable.java:92)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.variable.listener.support.VariableListenerSupport.triggerVariableListenersInNotificationQueues(VariableListenerSupport.java:180)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners(AbstractScoreDirector.java:261)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.AbstractMove.doMoveOnly(AbstractMove.java:27)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.AbstractMove.doMove(AbstractMove.java:20)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.AbstractMove.doMove(AbstractMove.java:15)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.doAndProcessMove(AbstractScoreDirector.java:206)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.doMove(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:116)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.decideNextStep(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:90)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:48)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:83)
> at
> org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:193)
> at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.java:40)

How can I fixe it ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged` and `scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged` need to be called with "y" (the custom shadow variable that will be changed by the variable listener), not "x" (the genuine planning variable that triggered the change; `x` is an "upstream" variable for `y` since `y` depends on `x`). Change your `afterVariableChange` method to:

```
@Override
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<Planningsolution> scoreDirector, variable sourcevariable) {
    
    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(sourcevariable, "y");
    sourcevariable.setY(sourcevariable.getX()*10);
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(sourcevariable, "y");

}
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to be the problem, it is working now.